# Object reinitialization : memory allocation

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, object

Was Learning Multithread Socket programming in java :

Came across this piece of code :

```
ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(8888);

while(true){
        counter++;
        Socket serverClient=server.accept();
        Threads t = new Threads(serverclient)
        }
```

Here For every connection we are creating an Object of Threads(class which has Implemented Runnable Interface).

My query is :
We are not creating a new object but re initializing the same object with new value.
So after re initializing new object reference the old object reference should get deleted

So Created this code to understand the constructor working in java.

```
public class free_memory
{

    public static void main(String args [])
    {   int i;

        long UsedMem=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Total memory used before execution : " + UsedMem / 1024);

        new temp();

        UsedMem=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Total memory used after  execution of 1 constructor: " + UsedMem/ 1024);

        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        new temp();
        }//for

        UsedMem=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Total memory used after  execution of 10 constructor: " + UsedMem/ 1024);


        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        temp a = new temp();
        }//for

        UsedMem=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Total memory used after  execution of 10 constructor: " + UsedMem/ 1024);

        int a;

        UsedMem=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Allocating an integer: " + UsedMem/ 1024);
    }//main
}



class temp
{
    int a[] = new int[10];
    int i;

    temp()
    {
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            a[i] = 10;
        }//for

    }//constructor


}//class
```

Output is :

```
Total memory used before execution : 1599
Total memory used after  execution of 1 constructor: 2048
Total memory used after  execution of 10 constructor: 2048
Total memory used after  execution of 10 constructor: 2048
Allocating an integer: 2048
```

This code is not allocating any extra memory.

Could you please help 
We should create an array of objects

// my suggestion it should be like this :

```
Socket serverClient=server.accept();
            Threads t[i] = new Threads(serverclient)
```

//original code

```
Socket serverClient=server.accept();
            Threads t = new Threads(serverclient)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Active Java threads are always considered live objects. They are not garbage collected for as long as they are running. Local variables are kept alive by the stack of a thread.

Comment: Re, "We are not creating a new object but re initializing the same object with new value." What object do you think is being re-initialized? It should be quite clear that `new Threads(...)` is creating a new instance of the `Threads` class. It also seems very likely that `server.accept()` creates and returns a new `Socket` instance each time.

Comment: Also, what is `Threads`, did you mean to write `Thread`?

Comment: @SolomonSlow : Thnx for your time!. Though new Threads() is creating a new instance but we are assigning to same objet name i.e. **t** so does the old reference gets removed.  `Threads t = new Threads(serverclient)`.  **Threads(class which has Implemented Runnable Interface).**

Comment: @rdas : Thnx for your time!.is this good practice or we should reference to new object name everytime for safer side `Threads t[i] = new Threads(serverclient)`

Comment: `serverClient` and `t` are not "object names." They are _[local variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable)_ in your `while` loop. Variables in the Java language never contain objects, they only _[refer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science))_ to objects. So, assigning new values to `serverClient` and `t` do not have any effect on any thread that was started in a previous iteration of the loop.

Comment: Understanding variables and object references and object lifetimes is _fundamental_ to understanding Java. You really should spend more time learning that stuff before you attempt to write multi-threaded code.

Comment: @SolomonSlow So if I have to refer any old active thread how we should refer them if we don't have the reference name(local variable).

Comment: Yes, If you need to keep references to more than one `Thread`, then you will have to store those references in some kind of a _[container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_(abstract_data_type))_, and then later, when you need a reference to a specific `Thread`, it will be up to you to write code that knows how to find the right one in the container.

Comment: @SolomonSlow : So this is the workaround right! `Threads t[i] = new Threads(serverclient)` using this now i can access a particular thread. Thnx!

Comment: Well, no, it isn't, as that nonsense doesn't even compile.